# Difficulty with Printing to Magento 2 Error Log

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to print messages to a Magento 2 error log so I can debug a module.  I am new to Magento 2 core programming, and I haven't been able to get messages to print to error logs.  I am trying to print to my debug.log file which I have made sure has write permissions.  I have tried the Method 1 and Method 3 in the following website

https://magecomp.com/blog/print-log-in-magento-2/

I am testing this in am module called MyTest, a basic Hello World module created according to the instructions in this website

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-create-hello-world-module-magento-2.html

The module itself works correctly, but I am trying to add lines at the end of MyTest/Controller/Index/Test.php to print "This is a test" to the file "/chroot/home/a8a17bee/afeb883cf6.nxcli.net/var/log/debug.log".

The file MyTest/Controller/Index/Test.php looks like this

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\MyTest\Controller\Index;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
        exit;
    }
}
```

I have tried inserting both chunks of code

```
$objectmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$objectmanager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug('This is a test');
```

and

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/chroot/home/a8a17bee/afeb883cf6.nxcli.net/var/log/debug.log');

$logger->addWriter($writer);

$logger->info('This is a test');
```

both inside the Test class and directly after it and neither printed the message to the log when I ran "php bin/magento setup:upgrade".  Does anyone have advice on what is going wrong?